# cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') - Can anyone help me out in this?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is my code and it's showing cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error.
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error
cannot set properties of null (setting 'innertext') error

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="../../scripts/cal/calendar-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" src="../../scripts/cal/calendar-setup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" src="../../scripts/cal/calendar_validations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/ClientScript.js"></script>

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function onPopupShownpopTop(s, e) {
        var windowInnerWidth = window.innerWidth;
        if (s.GetWidth() > windowInnerWidth) {
            s.SetWidth(windowInnerWidth - 4);
            s.UpdatePosition();
        }
    }
    function HidePopupLocAndShowInfo(d, winArgs) {
        setLOC_Values(winArgs[0], winArgs[1]);
        popTop.Hide();
    }
    function HidePopupVoyAndShowInfo(v, winArgs) {
        if (voy == 'fromvoy') {
            setVoyage_Values(winArgs[0], winArgs[1]);
        } else {
            setTrnsVoyage_Values(winArgs[0], winArgs[1]);
        }
        
        popTop.Hide();
    }
    function HidePopupPartnerAndShowInfo(p, winArgs) {
        setBkgParty_Values(winArgs[0], winArgs[1]);
        popTop.Hide();
    }
    function HidePopupPlacePayAndShowInfo(p, winArgs) {
        setPlaceofPay_Values(winArgs[0]);
        popTop.Hide();
    }
    function newWindow(url) {
        window.open(url, "", 'height=' + screen.height + ', width=' + screen.width + ', toolbar=no, left=0,top=0, menubar=no, titlebar=no, status=yes', '_self')
    }


    function OpenModal(link, AttachTo, top, left, height, width) {
        var ScrWidth = GetScrWidth();
        var ScrHeight = GetScrHeight();

        document.getElementById('ParentDiv').style.width = ScrWidth;
        document.getElementById('ParentDiv').style.height = ScrHeight;
        document.getElementById('ParentDiv').style.display = 'block';

        var winSettings = 'center:no;resizable:yes;help:no;status:no;dialogWidth:' + width + 'px;dialogHeight:' + height + 'px;dialogTop:' + top + '; dialogLeft:' + left + ''

        // return the dialog control values after passing them as a parameter
        winArgs = window.showModalDialog(link, '', winSettings);

        // see if the array is null
        if (winArgs == null) {
            document.getElementById('ParentDiv').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            // set the values from what's returned
            if (AttachTo == 'Partner') {
                setBkgParty_Values(winArgs[0], winArgs[1])
            }
            else if (AttachTo == 'Location') {
                setLOC_Values(winArgs[0], winArgs[1]);
            }
            else if (AttachTo == 'Voyage') {
                setVoyage_Values(winArgs[0], winArgs[1]);
            }
            else if (AttachTo == 'TrnsVoyage') {
                setTrnsVoyage_Values(winArgs[0], winArgs[1]);
            }
            else if (AttachTo == 'PlaceofPay') {
                setPlaceofPay_Values(winArgs[0]);
            }
            document.getElementById('ParentDiv').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    function GetScrWidth() {
        return document.body.scrollWidth;
    }
    //Get The Heigth of the scroller bar 

    function GetScrHeight() {
        return document.body.scrollHeight;
    }

    function setBkgParty_Values(Code, Desc) {
        document.getElementById('<%=txtBkg_Party_Cd.ClientId%>').value = Code;
        document.getElementById('<%=txtBkg_Party_Desc.ClientId%>').value = Desc;
    }

    function setPlaceofPay_Values(Code) {
        document.getElementById('<%=txtPlacePay.ClientId%>').value = Code;
    }

    function setVoyage_Values(Code, Desc) {
        document.getElementById('<%=txtVoyRef.ClientId%>').value = Code;
        document.getElementById('<%=txtVessel.ClientId%>').value = Desc;
    }

    function setTrnsVoyage_Values(Code, Desc) {
        document.getElementById('<%=txtTrnsVoyage.ClientId%>').value = Code;
        document.getElementById('<%=txtTrnsVoyageDesc.ClientId%>').value = Desc;
    }

    function setLOC_Values(Code, Desc) {
        if (towhich == '1')      // PLACE OF ORIGIN
        {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtPOO_Cd.ClientId%>').value = Code;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtPOO_Desc.ClientId%>').value = Desc;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtPOL_Cd.ClientId%>').select();
        }
        else if (towhich == '2')  //PORT OF LOADING
        {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtPOL_Cd.ClientId%>').value = Code;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtPOL_Desc.ClientId%>').value = Desc;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtPOD_Cd.ClientId%>').select();
        }
        else if (towhich == '3')  //PORT OF DISCHARGE
        {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtPOD_Cd.ClientId%>').value = Code;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtPOD_Desc.ClientId%>').value = Desc;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtFPD_Cd.ClientId%>').select();
        }
        else if (towhich == '4')  //FINAL DESTINATION
        {
            document.getElementById('<%=txtFPD_Cd.ClientId%>').value = Code;
            document.getElementById('<%=txtFPD_Desc.ClientId%>').value = Desc;
        }
    }


    var towhich;
    function ShowLocationDiv(path, LocAttachTo) {
        towhich = LocAttachTo;
        if (towhich == '1')      // PLACE OF ORIGIN
        {
         //   OpenModal(path, 'Location', 220, 200, 280, 400)
        }
        else if (towhich == '2')  //PORT OF LOADING
        {
         //   OpenModal(path, 'Location', 240, 200, 280, 400)
        }
        else if (towhich == '3')  //PORT OF DISCHARGE
        {
          //  OpenModal(path, 'Location', 260, 200, 280, 400);
        }
        else if (towhich == '4')  //FINAL DESTINATION
        {
           // OpenModal(path, 'Location', 280, 200, 280, 400);
        }
    }

    function ShowBkgParty(path) {
      //  OpenModal(path, 'Partner', 400, 500, 280, 400)
    }

    function ShowPlaceofPay(path) {
       // OpenModal(path, 'PlaceofPay', 200, 200, 280, 400)
    }
    var voy ;
    function ShowVoyage(path) {
        voy = 'fromvoy';
       // OpenModal(path, 'Voyage', 300, 200, 280, 400)
    }

    function ShowTrnsVoyage(path) {
        voy = 'tovoy';
      //  OpenModal(path, 'TrnsVoyage', 300, 200, 280, 400)
    }

    function ShowPools(path) {
      //  OpenModal(path, 'Pool', 300, 200, 280, 400)
    }

    function SetPath(Val) {
        document.getElementById('<%=lblHeading.ClientId%>').innerText = document.getElementById('<%=Master.FindControl("hdnMasterPath").ClientID %>').value + ' > ' + Val;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The error means that `document.getElementById('<%=lblHeading.ClientId%>')` return null

Comment: Yes, but how can I solve the error?

Comment: Instead of looking at the source code, look at the final HTML in your browser (press Ctrl-U). Now look what it says inside the SetPath function and check that there's actually an element with the same id in your HTML. Because right now there isn't.

Comment: This error is very easy to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/cb6sLu7f/

Comment: In the FINAL HTML in browser, it's showing the following: document.getElementById('MainContent_lblHeading').innerText = document.getElementById('<%=Master.FindControl("hdnMasterPath").ClientID %>').value + ' > ' + Val;

Comment: Ok, since the error mentions .innerText that means there's no element that has `id="MainContent_lblHeading"`. Also, for some weird reason the `Master.FindControl("hdnMasterPath").ClientID` isn't evaluated